# Finding the percentage of "cracks" in a SEM image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, physics, pixel

We have Scanning Electron Microscope (SEM) images of a certain cathode material and my aim is to find how much percentage of the image is occupied by cracks. Any suggestions on how this can be done? Currently I just try to find the number of "darkest" pixels in the image and take the percentage with the total number of pixels in the image. [image]

Here is my code so far:

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required = True, help = "path to input image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blurred, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
#imageCanny = cv2.Canny(blurred, 100, 200, 3)


#total number of pixels in the image = 1280x960 = 1228800
count = cv2.countNonZero(thresh)
img, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(image, contours, -1, (0,255,255), 2)
print(count)
```

If I do `countNonZero(image)` I get the error `(-215) cn == 1 in function countNonZero`, but not when I do `countNonZero(thresh)`. Am I correctly finding the darkest pixels?

Comment: That's a really interesting problem. The challenge will be in determining what constitutes a "crack" as opposed to just an edge. Why are you blurring the image first? I think you would be better off doing some histogram analysis and using that to determine your threshold. It would help if you could post some of the processed/filtered images too.

Comment: @gavinb That's a good point. I will try histogram analysis and post some processed images.

Comment: `cv2.countNonZero()` can only be applied to a grayscale (1-channel) image

Answer (score 2):

If you define a "crack" as a dark pixel, then you can use `np.where()` to isolate cracks that are below some threshold. Essentially any pixel that is below this threshold will be defined as a crack. This will give you a grayscale image where you can use `cv2.countNonZero()` to determine the crack percentage. Using a threshold value of `30` (which can be adjusted in the range of `[0..255]`) here's the result:

[image]

```
Crack percentage: 16.74%
```

Code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image as grayscale, change all pixels less than some threshold to black
image = cv2.imread('1.jpg', 0)
w,h = image.shape
image[np.where(image <= 30)] = 0

# Count non-crack pixels
pixels = cv2.countNonZero(image)

# Calculate crack percentage
percentage = 100 - (pixels / (w * h)) * 100
print('Crack percentage: {:.2f}%'.format(percentage))

cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```